# Compute pointwise limit of $f_{n}(x) = 2^nx 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2^n}, 1 \frac{1}{2^n} < x < 1 $

Tags: real-analysis

Since $ 0\leq x/\leq \frac {1}{2^n}$, $2^n$ should be a decreasing function and clearly decreases to one $\forall x \in [0,\frac{1}{2^n}],$ but how should I go about proving  that the function limit is 1?

Answer (score 0):

Given a $x\in(0,1]$, taking $n$ sufficiently large we have that$$\frac{1}{2^n}<x,$$
therefore $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=1$. But if $x=0$, then $x<\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$; which leads to $f(0)=0$.